# c# inheritance: casting of parent object to child

Tags: c#, inheritance, casting

We know that it is not possible to cast a parent object to one of its child classes.

So what is a good approach to solve the following problem:
Let's say I've got a parent class "Person" and two child classes: Customer and Employee. Note that the Person class is **not** abstract (meaning it can be instanciated).
Now I got the following method signature:

```
public Person GetPersonById(long id)
```

This makes it possible to either return a Person, or one of its child classes.
If I use this method, I can check via GetType() whether if it's a child or not. However, I can not easily access the fields/methods specific to the child class because I can't just cast it. 
One approach would be to implement a constructor for each child class that takes the parent class as parameter and returns a new child class-instance. This has the drawback that I still would have a lot of duplicate code (because I have to assign every parent-field in every child as well).

Another approach I can think of would be to change the method to this:

```
public object GetPersonById(long id)
```

That way, I could return any class. I'd just check the type of the returned class and then cast it properly. But somehow, this approach seems dirty.

Does anybody have a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But in fact you can cast a parent object to it's child type, IF the object is of that type

Comment: Okay, I know why I came to the wrong assumption that you can't cast parents to childs: I was using Entity Framework and it creates proxy classes and I always matched the type of the proxy-class and so it would never work.

Answer (score 4):

You can cast `Person` to `Customer` if it really is a `Customer`:

```
var customer = person as Customer;
if(customer != null)
{
    // the person was really a Customer
}
```

If you'd like you could create three methods instead of one:

```
public Person GetPersonById(long id)
public Customer GetCustomerById(long id)
public Employee GetEmployeeById(long id)
```

Or use Generics (but I feel bad about generics in that particular case):

```
public T GetPersonById<T>(long id) where T : Person
```

And call it:

```
var person = GetPersonById<Employee>(123);
```

But you still need to specify what you're trying to get at call time.

Comment: Nice answer, and why do you feel bad about generics in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Use "is" keyword

```
if(instance is ChildClass)
{
    //...
}
```